# Extending Apache Superset and adding a link

Tags: python-3.x, flask, apache-superset, flask-appbuilder

I have a superset fork I managed to get it up and running using docker compose. Now I'm trying to do one simple thing: add a new link to the existing SQL Lab menu.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is use `appbuilder.add_link` under the `init_views` method of the `SupersetAppInitializer` class (app.py):

```
class SupersetAppInitializer:

    # ...

    def init_views(self) -> None:

        # ...
       
        appbuilder.add_link(
            __("Saved Queries"),
            href="/savedqueryview/list/",
            icon="fa-save",
            category="SQL Lab",
        )
        # This is a new link
        appbuilder.add_link(
            __("Test"),
            href="/savedqueryview/list/",
            icon="fa-save",
            category="SQL Lab",
        )
```

I copied the existing 'Saved Queries' link and added a 'Test' link (using the same href). It doesn't seem to be working.

What do I need to make it work?

Comment: i think superset using Automatic menu generation based on flask-appbuilder and It's diferend think **add_link** with **add_view**, [check this](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html?highlight=menu%20generation#changing-menu-construction)

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue by editing the changes to the app menu in vim.

The way Apache superset builds the menu is by [requesting data from the backend](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/v2021.15.0/superset/views/base.py#L337).

When editing `superset/app.py` in `vim`, changes to it are not [properly updated to file mounts in the running container.](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793)

You could configure your editor to perform edits in place.
Another option is to restart the container services to rebind the file mounts.